# Getting string from cmd output

Tags: cmd, findstr

I am running a command that produces the following output -

```
                           Processing/
2019-02-07 12:10:43        305 Test1.csv
2019-02-07 12:11:43        306 Test2.csv
```

How can I use `findstr` to extract the file name. For example, `Test1.csv` and `Test2.csv`

Comment: How do you want to extract it? In what variable? Do you want just to `echo` it?

Comment: `findstr` does not extract parts from lines, it always returns full matching lines....

Comment: Is this text coming from a `DIR` command or from a flat-text log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `findstr`. You may use:

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=4" %%A IN ('command') do (
    echo %%A
)
```

to `echo` the string you want.

If you don't want to `echo` them, do them whatever you want: assign them to a variable, e.t.c., but remember that they are assigned in the `for` loop variable **`%%A`**.